# How to check the decimal position AngularJS

Tags: javascript

I am working with a value such as `var number = 23.8981`   I need to check the 4th number after the decimal and determine if it is a number that is not 0. I am uncertain how to go about this check. I am new to angularjs so any help with this particular problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could make use of some javascript logic like one below.

```js
const number = 23.8981;
const fourthDigit = number * 10000 % 10;
console.log(fourthDigit);
```